# Unir csv con varias columnas en Python

Tags: python, csv

Necesito unir, en este caso, dos csv que tienen 10 columnas cada uno. Con este código logré unirlos, pero solo me toma una columna:

```
def junta_csv(salida, archivos):
"""
Crea un archivo .csv a partir de multiples
archivos .csv con una sola columna

:param salida: Nombre del archivo de salida.
:param archivos: Lista de archivos de entrada.
                 Son .csv con header en la primera fila.
"""
handles = [] # Archivos de entrada
headers = [] # Headers de cada archivo de entrada
#
#   Abrir los archivos de entradas, leer los headers
#
for arch in archivos:
    file_handle = open(arch, "r")
    handles.append(file_handle)
    headers.append(file_handle.readline().strip())

with open(salida, "w") as out:
    #   Formar la primera linea con los headers de
    #   las columnas.
    header = ",".join(headers)
    out.write(f"{header}\n")

    eof = False
    while not eof:
        fila = []
        #   Leer una fila de cada archivo para
        #   formar una fila de salida.
        for handle in handles:
            dato = handle.readline()
            if dato:
                fila.append(dato.strip())
            else:
                eof = True
                break

        if not eof:
            #   Grabar la fila de salida.
            salida = ','.join(fila)
            out.write(f"{salida}\n")

#   Cerrar tosdos los archivos
out.close()
for handle in handles:
    handle.close()
```

Luego, la inicializo de la siguiente manera:

```
archivos = ["arch1.csv", "arch2.csv"]
junta_csv("salida.csv", archivos)
```

También logré hacer la union de estos archivos en solo dos lineas:

```
with open('archivo1.csv','ab') as f:
    f.write (open ('archivo2.csv', 'rb'). read ())
```

El problema de este modo es que, si bien une todas las columnas presentes de ambos archivos, el segundo archivo lo ingresa en la parte de abajo.
Ejemplo:

```
Archivo1             Archivo2
A B C                D E F
1 2 3                1 2 3
4 5 6                4 5 6 

Resultado:
Archivo
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
D E F
1 2 3
4 5 6
Resultado esperado:
A B C D E F
1 2 3 1 2 3
4 5 6 4 5 6
```

El primer código que implemente, el que aparece arriba de todo de la pregunta, lo une en el sentido que necesito de izquierda a derecha. Sin embargo, solo me toma una columna.
El segundo código, me toma todas las columnas, pero hace la unión de arriba hacia abajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución sin utilizar ninguna librería externa, usando la librería [csv](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/csv.html) incluida en Python:

```
import csv

with open("csv1.csv", newline='') as csv1, \
     open("csv2.csv", newline='') as csv2, \
     open("destino.csv", "w") as dest:

    writer = csv.writer(dest)
    
    for csv1_line, csv2_line in zip(csv.reader(csv1), csv.reader(csv2)):
        writer.writerow((*csv1_line, *csv2_line))
```

La idea sería abrir 3 archivos. Los primeros 2 serían los csv a unir, y el ultimo el csv a crear. Luego recorro cada registro en paralelo usando zip, y finalmente uno las dos lineas en una sola tupla para escribirlos en el csv de destino.

La ventaja de usar esto en lugar de pandas es que te evitas cargar totalmente ambos csvs en memoria (solo cargas un registro a la vez en memoria). Pero no tiene todas las ventajas que trae Pandas.

Comment: Gracias! Es justo lo que necesitaba

Comment: De nada Pablo c:

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Una forma muy fácil y rápida de hacerlo es utilizando el módulo `pandas`y en específico, el método [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Teniendo dos `dataframe`

```
Dataframe 1
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6

Dataframe 2
    D   E   F
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
```

Lo único que hay que hacer es concatenar en `axis=1` (Como dice en la documentación agregada en el link, esto significa concatenar columnas)

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
```

Esto devuelve:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F
0   1   2   3   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   4   5   6
```

La ventaja es que también con `pandas` puedes leer los datos de los csv y crear `dataframes` para manipularlos como desees

Y lo que tendrías que hacer es simplemente escribir este nuevo `dataframe` en tu archivo de salida

Comment: Gracias! Voy a probar esta alternativa tambien!